# SOM initial values for learning rate and neighborhood sigma

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I am using SOM (Self-Organizing Maps) of Kohonen, or more specifically, the MiniSom, [found here](https://github.com/JustGlowing/minisom) to cluster and visualize my data.

As you can see in the above site, the example given is:

```
from minisom import MiniSom    
som = MiniSom(6, 6, 4, sigma=0.3, learning_rate=0.5) # initialization of 6x6 SOM
print "Training..."
som.train_random(data, 100) # trains the SOM with 100 iterations
print "...ready!"
```

the three parameters of **sigma** and **learning rate** and **number of iterations** are hardcoded, and apparently it is working for the given examples. However, my data is bigger and different in size, so when I use these hardcoded parameters, the results is awful. Or even worse, when I change my corpus and implement it on another corpus size, the results get worse... however when I try to find the "best initial values" by trial and error, I get something that is meaningful!

### Question:

How can I determine the initial values of these parameters? Is there any other SOM implementation that facilitates this?

Your comments and answers are welcome. thanks.

### annex:

There is an [article](https://www.academia.edu/30688343/Improving_Feature_Map_Quality_of_SOM_Based_on_Adjusting_the_Neighborhood_Function) on this, but apparently no right answer...